# Host alias/mini-DNS?

Tags: python-requests

I'd like to define session aliases so the following works:

```
s = requests.Session()
# define 'https://server' -> 'https://example.com:12345' somehow
s.get('https://server/resource')
```

For http, using `proxies` does the expected, but it seems to be a coincidence/misuse (fails for https):

```
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies['http://server'] = 'http://example.com:12345'
s.get('http://server/resource')
```

Using transport adapter should be possible but is likely an overkill.

What is the correct/preferred way?

Comment: in your example , you define a wrong proxy. did you follow http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies ?

Comment: @kcorlidy I suspect my `proxies` is wrong, but for some reason it does work for *http*